# Low voltage (<3V) signalling on USB DP/DN - will it work?

Tags: stm32, low-power, usb-device

I'm using a microcontroller (specifically, the STM32L1) that integrates a USB device full-speed interface. I want to supply it with just 2V VDD, which is within spec for that micro. But that means USB pins DP and DN, in particular, will be driven high to 2V, while the USB standard calls for a high level voltage of 3V. 
I suspect that, since USB signalling is differential, driving DP and DN to 2V only would still allow proper operation (event though that would not pass USB certification).  Is this a correct assumption ?
Thanks -

Comment: I'm struggling to understand your motives here. If it works it might be flaky or work great on ONE particular device. Try another device and it won't necessarily work. Now where does this get you?

Comment: No, that is not a correct assumption. You want to design one device that does not meet the standard and connect it to other devices that do meet the standard. All bets are off.

Answer (score 1):

The voltage standard for USB is based on a loss over a certain cable length.  If you are using this in a known configuration for a single use setup, you may be fine.  But I would expect issues with lesser quality cables or getting close to the lengths people expect USB to work.

For a reference to this, USB3 is 1 V signalling, with a 100 mV required at received.  I would look for the minimums for USB2 and see how large of a margin you still have.

Comment: For full-speed (USB2 at 12Mbps), a logic 1 or 0 at receiver side is defined by a differential of 200mV, just 10% of 2V. However I'm not sure if speed identification, for example (normally done by pulling DP or DN to 3V3) is also detected differentially ?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the USB, the best is to have a separate power supply at 3V powering the I/O
THis is made possible on the STM32F0x8 as there are 2 separate voltage domains. A 1.8V for the digital portion, and few I/Os at 3.3V with the USB.